# Send message to console.log (jest puppeteer)

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, puppeteer

Why I can't see my messages at console.log in `page.evaluate`, `page.$`, `page.$$`, `page.$eval`, `page.$$eval`
And can't to get access to variables out that?

```
let variable = 0;
const divColors = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.map-filters div'));
      let text = divs.map((element, index) => {
        console.log(element.textContent)
        variable =1;
        return element.style.color;
      })
      return text;
    })
```

Why I can't do `variable=1` and `console.log(element.textContent)` in this example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using `console.log` inside of `page.evaluate`, so it is logging its output to the Chromium browser and not to node output. To see console messages from browser in node's console one needs to subscribe to them after `page` object is created and before `console.log` is used in the script:

```
const page = await browser.newPage();

page.on('console', consoleObj => console.log(consoleObj.text()));

page.evaluate(...);
```

As for `variable` variable, there are in fact two of them in your script.

The first one exists in node.js context:

```
let variable = 0;
```

And the other one — in web page context:

```
page.evaluate( () => {
    variable = 1;
})
```

They are completely different. Think of `page.evaluate` as of a portal into another world: objects that exist there are only present inside of a javascript runtime on a page open in the web browser that `puppeteer` is driving. `node` has its own runtime with its own set of objects.

You may pass data into `page.evaluate` from `node`:

```
let variable = 420;

page.evaluate(variable => {

    // it is now passed here from outside
    console.log(variable) 

}, variable);
```

Comment: Ok, thanks about it. What about variables? How can I use variable inner evaluate?

Comment: How about $$eval or $$ ? Can I pass data to it?

Comment: Yes, you can pass data to $eval and $$eval, see the excellent puppeteer documentation: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args